# Static properties from Generic parameters in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Question:

1. How can I reify `object` types when specified as a Generic Parameter
2. Or, How can I implement Static properties in Kotlin?

I know the closest thing we have to static data is using `object`.

**Simple Example**

Having an interface which will only be implemented by Objects

```
interface SomeObject {
    val someProperty: String
}

object AnObject: SomeObject {
    override val someProperty = "someValue"
}
```

And using the interface as a generic constraint, I would like to be able to access these properties statically.

```
class GenericClass<O: SomeObject> { 

    var someValue: String
        get() = O.someProperty   // This is not possible
}

GenericClass<AnObject>().someValue
```

The only way would be to also pass the object as a constructor parameter

```
class GenericClass<O: SomeObject>(
    val obj: O
) { 
    var someValue: String
        get() = obj.someProperty
}

GenericClass(AnObject).someValue
```

Repeating the question above

1. Is there a way to reify this object?
2. Or, is there any other way to implement static properties on Types?

Comment: @Sweeper One way I have found is to use Reflection
`inline fun <reified T> getObjectInstance(): T? = T::class.objectInstance`
Any other way of having static data?

Comment: I guess you can have an inline factory function that creates `GenericClass<O>` objects... One that throws an exception if `objectInstance` is null. Does that sound good to you?

Comment: I'm also interested in the use-case; it feels like this is trying to accomplish some strange scenario that could be better solved differently (just guessing since you didn't provide more context here)

Comment: @Sweeper I guess that would have to do for now.
On Swift for example, the same can be achieved by `static let` properties which can be accessible on Generic type parameters as well.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini 
I would like to provide an API in a library which let's users implement different `GenericClass` instances based on generated code objects.
Both the `GenricClass` API and Objects to be passed therein will be provided by this library.

Comment: I see, well, swift's static let doesn't have the burden of the JVM, and I have the impression this is difficult for the JVM due to generic type erasure, but I may be wrong. I would have a factory to construct the generic objects anyway, to have more control, but without sitting in front of the problem, I'm just another id10t behind a keyboard :) (and with the problem I'm still an id10t behind a keyboard, but with a problem to solve in front) :)

Comment: In the comments you said, "Objects to be passed therein will be provided by this library". If that's the case, you can mark the interface as a sealed interface. The sealed interface would guarantee users have to pick one of your implementations, which are all objects, so they don't have constructors. Alternatively, you could use an enum class, where each member of the class has one of your implementations.

Comment: As an alternative way to use reflection, you can create a mock constructor for your GenericClass in a companion object using `inline operator fun <reified T: SomeObject> invoke(): GenericClass<T> = GenericClass(T::class.objectInstance ?: error("unsupported type"))`. If it's a sealed interface, you know it's safe from getting a type with no associated object. Unless the interface SomeObject itself is given as the type. You could provide a default behavior instead of throwing if you want.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Yes, I understand. The factory method with reification and errors seems to be the best approach for now.
Thanks for supporting a fellow id10t :)

Comment: I just added an answer to the question based on our discussion here. Have a look and let me know if anything looks wrong  :). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

One way to reify the object is using reflection:

```
inline fun <reified T> getObject(): T? = T::class.objectInstance
```

If you are really sure the generic type will be an object

```
inline fun <reified T> getObject(): T = T::class.objectInstance ?: error("Not an object!")
```

This can be used within a mock constructor for GenericClass

```
class GenericClass private constructor(private val obj: O) {

    var someValue: String
        get() = obj.someProperty

    companion object {
        inline operator fun <reified T: SomeObject> invoke(): GenericClass<T> = 
            GenericClass(T::class.objectInstance ?: error("unsupported type"))
    }
}
```

And can be called as desired using only a generic parameter

```
GenericClass<AnObject>().someValue
```